# Examples of continuous measures in R

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying measure theory and I've read the definition of a *continuous* measure in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$: a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=0~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know some examples of continuous measures other than the Lebesgue measure. So far, I have been able to come up with the measure
$$\mu(A)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
0,&\text{if A is countable} \\
+\infty,&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.,$$

but perthaps there are other, more meaningful or interesting measures which satisfy that property.

Comment: Take any measure which has a density wrt to Lebegue,  namely, $$\mu(A) = \int_A f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x$$ for an integrable $f$.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to find one that also satisfies $\mu(\mathbb{R})=+\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Take $f$ locally integrable but not integrable, for example $f(x) = x^2$ would do.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you very much!